# Responsive nav bar will not center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am making a responsive html website using bootstrap and I cannot seem to be able to center the nav bar of my website at a certain viewing point. 
(I put it in pastbin since it was a lot of code, sorry.)

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/1GpEHgbE)

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/kkpcFVpj)

Website(Resize the window to see what I mean.): shanebacon.com

Comment: can you add to fiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because you're using `position: fixed` on your nav bar which breaks the element out of the flow of the document. So `margin: auto` wont have an effect. But you do have a fixed width of `1000px` so you can use this:

```
.masthead.nav{
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -500px;
}
```

What this does is move your nav to the left `50%` but it's not 50% from the center but from the left corner. So you need to use a negative margin (which is half the width) to bring the nav back to the middle.

**Also note**: it appears these classes are all looped together:

```
.masthead, .mastfoot, .masthead .inner {
   width: 1000px;
   position: sticky;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Don't add this to all three, it will throw off your CSS. Be sure to only add it to `.masthead` or `.masthead.nav`

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0zqtz31v/)